# É possível realizar uma adição com campo varchar?

Tags: sql-server

tenho o seguinte update:

```
update ex      
set ex.seq_docum_ref = '00001',    
    ex.nr_chv_nfe_ref = ref.ChaveNfTerceiro,         
    ex.cd_docum_ref = case when ChaveNfTerceiro is not null then coalesce(ref.DocSispro,'') else case when ref.SerieNotaProd is not null then 'NFP'+cast(ref.SerieNotaProd as varchar) else '' end end,         
    ex.cd_docum_nr_ref = ref.NrNfTerceiro,         
    ex.cd_pessoa_ref = ex.cd_pessoa_emi,         
    ex.dt_nota_ref = replace(convert(varchar, ref.DtNfTerceiro,103),'/',''),         
    ex.in_ent_sai = 'S'
```

no campo

```
ex.seq_docum_ref
```

quero que ele some mais um a cada update realizado, no entanto o campo é varchar, como posso fazer essa adição e manter o tipo do campo? Preciso disso para entregar uma tarefa no trabalho.
Desde já obrigado!

Comment: Dá pra você fazer a operação com um convert, mas o ideal mesmo é alterar esse campo para um numérico.

Comment: @gmsantos Poderia me exemplificar a operação com convert?

Comment: @RenanGoulart `SELECT CONVERT(int, '42') + CONVERT(int, '42')` retorna 84 por exemplo.

Comment: Para o seu caso, seria melhor dar uma olhada na definição de `trigger`, é o que você vai precisar.

Comment: @ThRnk fiquei na duvida de como aplicaria isso nesse update, teria algum exemplo por favor?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Se não errei na sintaxe, experimente algo como

```
UPDATE ex      
  set seq_docum_ref= right (('0000' + cast ((cast (seq_docum_ref as int) +1) as varchar(5))), 5), 
  ...
```

Mas o melhor mesmo é utilizar uma tabela auxiliar para armazenar o contador como valor numérico e, sempre que for necessário obter a próxima sequência, solicitá-la e então armazenar na tabela convertendo para string com zeros à esquerda. No artigo [Geração de sequências numéricas](https://portosql.wordpress.com/2019/04/21/geracao-de-sequencias-numericas/) você encontra formas de gerar uma sequência confiável.